# Why does MS Windows File Explorer not see my external drives sometimes when I've been working with them in Linux

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I use Linux mostly from day to day. I transfer a lot of material between drives and have become very familiar with the ins and outs. However, today I went to Windows to use a Windows program to create a USB with an ISO from an external drive I'd been using on Ubuntu.
Windows File Explorer could not see the drive even though it was visible in the Disk Management program. Unfortunately, the option to give the drive a Path and assign a drive letter was not in the menu when right clicking the drive.
Is there something in Ubuntu that I'm missing? I always unmount the drive before disconnecting although, when rebooting I don't physically disconnect.
Thanks to anyone else that has come across this and has a fix...

Comment: What is the file system of that particular drive?

Comment: Solved - I went to Linux to check the drive again and found that the file system is ext4. Obviously not a lot can be done with this so I copied my ISO from the drive to gard drive on the Windows partition. Sorry for the foopah!!! It just shows that someone that has been using Linux for years can still trip over their own feet...

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I went to Linux to check the drive again and found that the file system is ext4. Obviously not a lot can be done with this so I copied my ISO from the drive to gard drive on the Windows partition. Sorry for the foopah!!! It just shows that someone that has been using Linux for years can still trip over their own feet...

Answer (score 0):

Check the file system of that drive. If it is EXT4, you will have that issue. Windows is completely incompatible with EXT4. You will have to change it to NTFS.